# Calling MSBuild Tasks from within a Custom Task

Tags: c#-4.0, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is it possible to invoke other MSBuild tasks (CL, Link, Delete, MakeDir, etc.) from within a Custom (inline or non inline) Task which is being invoked via a MSBuild Project File? Something like:

```
<!-- In MSBuild File -->
<MyStrangeTask />
```

And in C# Code implementing "MyStrangeTask"

```
// After declaring class, properties, etc.
public override bool Execute()
{
    // Call other MSBuild Tasks here: CL, Link, MakeDir, etc.
}
```

Yes, it might be possible to duplicate functionality of some of the tasks (Delete, MakeDir, etc.) but why re-invent the wheel? Besides, tasks such as CL and Link would be time consuming to re-implement.

*Why i need this?*

i am writing a custom task which basically needs to do copying files, invoking CL preprocessor, etc. One may question the very design of such a "huge" task but let's just say some requirements force us to walk this "tedious" path.

---

**EDIT:** *to emphasize the correct context of this question*

This question is not from a design but a **technical perspective**.

Being a novice in this field, i just wish to know is this technically possible? If Yes, how? If Not, why not?

Comment: If you split your custom task in logical parts you don't need this. You just make an msbuild target that first copies files using eg Copy, then calls CL, Link, MakeDir etc.

Comment: You could invent a simple machine that when positioned alongside another object of relative size and mass would facilitate the object's movement by "rotating" along an "axis" thereby reducing friction.  We'll call this a "wheel" and design this with four corners.

Comment: Hahaha.. :) Yes, (as mentioned in my question) i do comprehend the fact that this is not a good design but to quote again "_let's just say some requirements force us to walk this "tedious" path_".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can find classes used for MSBuild tasks at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.aspx).
But you should note that it's explicitly written:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and **is not intended to be used directly from your code**

Also you can find example of such usage in this [blog post](http://codefocus.blogspot.com/2008/10/running-msbuild-tasks-programatically.html).

So that is answer to what you asked, but maybe there is different solution that you need: You can break your task into many sub-tasks: output from first custom task is sent to MSBuild project that can be used by built-in tasks and output of built-in task sent into your second custom task and so on.

Comment: Yes, thank You for the pointer.. i searched and found a class of CL  Task (Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL). i am not intending to use them directly from my code. The question arose out of curiosity.

Comment: Just in case the link dies: http://web.archive.org/web/20161024064310/http://codefocus.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/running-msbuild-tasks-programatically.html